# Conditional split on creating new columns using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data where in column 'Type', I have set of currencies. I created new columns based on these currencies. But i am not sure how to give a condition like if the type is btc then create these columns, like wise i have more categories in that column. The sample data looks like this.

Given:

```
Type    Last                 
ada     3071.56         
ada     3097.82          
btc     1000.00
ada     2000.00
btc     3000.00
eur     1000.00
eur     1500.00
```

Expected:

```
Type    Last        changbtwread_ada    changbtwread_btc  changbtwread_eur         
ada     3071.56          Nan                 Nan               Nan
ada     3097.82          26.0                Nan               Nan
btc     1000.00          Nan                 Nan               Nan 
ada     2000.00         -1097.82             Nan               Nan
btc     3000.00          Nan                 2000              Nan
eur     1000.00          Nan                 Nan               Nan
eur     1500.00          Nan                 Nan               500
```

The code i tried to create this change between reading for one type is as follow:

```
df['changbtwread'] = df['Last'].diff()
```

But what i want is for all types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop by unique values and create difference to new columns created by `f-string`s:

```
for v in df['Type'].unique():
    df[f'changbtwread_{v}'] = df.loc[df['Type'].eq(v), 'Last'].diff()
print (df)
  Type     Last  changbtwread_ada  changbtwread_btc  changbtwread_eur
0  ada  3071.56               NaN               NaN               NaN
1  ada  3097.82             26.26               NaN               NaN
2  btc  1000.00               NaN               NaN               NaN
3  ada  2000.00          -1097.82               NaN               NaN
4  btc  3000.00               NaN            2000.0               NaN
5  eur  1000.00               NaN               NaN               NaN
6  eur  1500.00               NaN               NaN             500.0
```

Comment: I dont want to group by. Could you please give solution without groupby.

Comment: @KSp - So it seems not understand what need. Is possible add next 2 rows to expected output?

Comment: Please check now.