# How to get the timestamp calculation using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find at what time period the price was low and high in percentage.

The data looks like this

```
    Last    Timestampvalue  

2   3071.56 1547986549
3   3097.82 1547986666
4   3097.82 1547986675
5   3095.25 1547986737
6   3087.42 1547986798
7   3095.29 1547986854
8   3095.25 1547986918
9   3093.11 1547986975
10  3103    1547987034
11  3095    1547987096
12  3100.6  1547987157
13  3099.84 1547987218
14  3098.77 1547987277
15  3097.24 1547987340
16  3090    1547987397
17  3090    1547987457
```

Expected

```
    Last    Timestampvalue   pct_Max

2   3071.56 1547986549
3   3097.82 1547986666
4   3097.82 1547986675
5   3095.25 1547986737
6   3087.42 1547986798
7   3095.29 1547986854
8   3095.25 1547986918
9   3093.11 1547986975
10  3103    1547987034
11  3095    1547987096
12  3100.6  1547987157
13  3099.84 1547987218
14  3098.77 1547987277
15  3097.24 1547987340
16  3090    1547987397
17  3090    1547987457         0.5341
18  3098    1547987519         0.5
```

Logic i expect is as follows,

(1547987034-1547986549)/(1547987457-1547986549) = 0.5341
(1547987034-1547986549)/(1547987519-1547986549) = 0.5

That is the Max value (3103) occurs at 10row and the time stamp here is 1547987034 and then i subtract it with the timestamp at row 2 (1547986549) and divide it by 15th minute timestamp which occurs at row 17 so the timestamp here is 1547987457 and subtract this with timestamp at row 2.

I know to calculate this in excel but in pandas i tried to just find which value is maximum at 15minutes and not sure how to get its timestamp and also it needs to be on type split as well.

```
for v in df['Type'].unique():
    mask = df['Type'].eq(v)
    df.loc[mask, f'Prev15minMax_{v}'] = (df.loc[mask,'Last']
                                           .rolling('15min',min_periods=15)
                                           .max())
```

Type column looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55862361/conditional-split-on-creating-new-columns-using-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

Here are your elements for your computation (broken down):

```
max_Last = df1.loc[df1['Last'] == df1['Last'].max(),'Timestampvalue']
max_ts = df1['Timestampvalue'].max()
min_ts = df1['Timestampvalue'].min()
cpt = (max_Last - min_ts) / (max_ts - min_ts)
```

Here is a way to get to your specified column:

```
df1['pct_Max'] = ''
df1.loc[df1['Timestampvalue'] == df1['Timestampvalue'].max(),'pct_Max'] = cpt
```

Comment: But i dont want to substract it with min_ts but i wanted to do the last value starting timestamp. Overall in 15minutes total

Comment: max_Last = df.loc[df['Last'] == df['Last'].rolling('15min',min_periods=15).max(),'Timestampvalue']
I tried this, but it doesnt really give me the timestamp of the max value for 15minutes timeframe.